# How to install ROS in ubuntu 13.04

Tags: ros, ros-groovy, beaglebone

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have installed ubuntu 13.04, my final project is development with beaglebone. I saw an article about installing ROS from the source tried it but didn`t work at all ! Is there is any other way to install ROS ?!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/64401/how-to-install-ros-in-ubuntu-13.04/) by [Sagacious](https://answers.ros.org/users/5064/sagacious/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-06-05

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on 2013-06-05**:
Please provide the link that you used

**Comment by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on 2013-06-05**:
Is this any help -- http://sysadminfixes.wordpress.com/2013/03/18/ros-on-beaglebuntu/ ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If at all possible, you'll probably have a much better time installing ubuntu 12.04 and using apt-get to install ROS groovy as described [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/groovy/Installation/Ubuntu).

I haven't played with a beaglebone, but [these](http://answers.ros.org/question/61312/ros-on-beaglebone-issues/) [questions](http://answers.ros.org/question/58966/ros-on-beaglebone/) may help, and they suggest that hydro on 13.04 is unnecessary.

---

Originally posted by [lindzey](https://answers.ros.org/users/2444/lindzey/) with karma: 1780 on 2013-06-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1